# How to compare two tar files in bash without using temporary files?

Tags: bash

I'm struggling to achieve folowing without temp. files.

```
#!/bin/bash
tar ztf "$1" | sort > tmp1
tar ztf "$2" | sort > tmp2
comm -1 -3 tmp{1,2}|while read line; do echo -e "$1: $line\n"; done
comm -2 -3 tmp{1,2}|while read line; do echo -e "$2: $line\n"; done
rm tmp{1,2}
```

how to do this without tmp files ?

Comment: As a minor optimization, you could use a single `comm` invocation, and replace the rather clumsy `while` loop with a sed script. `comm -3 one two | sed -e "s/^\t\/$1: /;t;s/\\t$//;s/^$2: /" | sort` (if your `sed` does not interpret `\t` as tab, use literal tabs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using each temp file twice, the answer is almost certainly no. However, if you modify the script to use a single command (e.g. `comm` by itself, or `diff`) then the following should work:

```
diff <(tar ztf "$1" | sort) <(tar ztf "$2" | sort)
```

This uses [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

(Also, just as an aside, one should use [`mktemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp) to create temporary files)

Comment: That one helped. I'm almost sure you have misspelled ztf as a option for tar.
How can i use grep to modify this result ?

Comment: @user90100, yep fixed the typo. You can use grep like in any other situation, i.e. just with pipe: `diff [...] | grep 'pattern'`.